# Deploy Meteor App Locally Windows

Tags: windows, deployment, meteor

I have a Meteor app that I would like to deploy to my server, which is a Windows server. I cannot deploy it to a meteor server because my project requires the writing and reading of files, which meteor prevents on their servers due to security issues. The reading and writing of files is required in my program; I cannot substitute it with writing to databases.

I'm using the current version of meteor from win.meteor.com (0.7.0.1).

Does anybody have a solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure they don't allow reading and writing of files on their server? Each app is sandboxed so long as you don't try and access files outside the sandbox nothing should be denied access. If you want to deploy it locally you can just run it with `--production` or create a `bundle` tarball and run it as a node js app.

Comment: I'm almost certain you can't read/write files, as my app worked locally but did not work deployed. I will try your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Akshat One of the installation instructions is

$ export MONGO_URL='mongodb://user:password@host:port/databasename'


However, export is a unix command. How would I do this on a windows machine?

Comment: You use `SET` instead of export see http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html for examples

Comment: @Akshat Using SET, I've inputted the proper variables but I get an error. Here is a pastebin of the code I used and the error it threw. Thank you for your help so far.
http://pastebin.com/BFBsDm6g

Comment: Your `ROOT_URL` needs to end in a `/` so use `http://subdomain.mysite.com/` instead of `http://subdomain.mysite.com`

Comment: @Akshat I tried what you did, but I'm still getting literally the same error message. To ensure my ROOT_URL was properly entered, I ran 'echo %ROOT_URL%, which returned, as expected, http://subdomain.mysite.com/, with the last slash there. I'm not sure what's wrong. I tried the same thing entering the MONGO_URL with a final slash an without one. `>node main.js` still returned the same error.

Comment: I'm a bit uncertain whether the app is running properly on its own, it might not be an issue with meteor for windows. If you try running it on Linux would it run? There was an issue with the error you're describing upgrading from Meteor 0.6.5 with namespacing. Did you upgrade your meteor app from an earlier version?

Comment: @Akshat I've looked at the source and it seems to be throwing errors because it's not interpreting the env variables correctly. `if(urlPrefix.charAt(0) !== '/') return 'a route URL prefix must begin with a slash';` This throws the initial error. I don't know why the first character of the URL would be a '/', but that's what's required. I commented that and I recieved another exception stating that my MONGO_URL was wrong, as it was supposed to start with a 'mongodb://', which it did! I think the SET method is not properly setting the environment variables.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44341/discussion-between-user2913631-and-akshat)

Answer (score 0):

The bundle generated by `meteor build` should have no dependencies on the `meteor` tool. You should just be able to run it as a normal node.js app.

Comment: I keep seeing this mentioned all over the intertubes, but how is that actually done I cannot find anywhere :(